# How to solve Error: spawn EACCES on Jenkins when running Karma?

Tags: node.js, jenkins, permissions, karma-runner, ubuntu-16.04

I have setup an AWS Codepipeline.

The pipeline uses Git as a source, Jenkins for testing and an EC2 instance for deployment.

The project is based on [Angular Starter by Angular Class](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter). Thus, it uses Karma for unit testing.

The Jenkins service runs on Ubuntu 16.04.

Karma uses Headless Chrome for testing.

The problem is that I currently get the folloing error when running the tests on Jenkins:

```
[31m07 05 2017 14:30:35.779:ERROR [karma]: [39m{ Error: spawn EACCES
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1050:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
    at exports.spawn (child_process.js:378:9)
    at spawnWithoutOutput (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleTask/node_modules/karma/lib/launchers/process.js:168:24)
    at Object.ProcessLauncher._execCommand (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleTask/node_modules/karma/lib/launchers/process.js:76:21)
    at Object.ProcessLauncher._start (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleTask/node_modules/karma/lib/launchers/process.js:33:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleTask/node_modules/karma/lib/launchers/process.js:19:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at Object.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Object.BaseLauncher.start (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleTask/node_modules/karma/lib/launchers/base.js:42:10)
    at Object.j (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleTask/node_modules/karma/lib/launcher.js:116:17)
    at Object.setTimeout.bind.j (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleTask/node_modules/qjobs/qjobs.js:143:18)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:386:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5) code: 'EACCES', errno: 'EACCES', syscall: 'spawn' }
```

I have already done some research with the following findings:

- other people also had similar errors but related to to other packages
- the error may be related to wrong permissions

What I have tried so far:

- checking the permissions of /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleTask ->
  result: owner is jenkins user
- give jenkins user root privileges (I know it is dangerous but I just wanted to try if it would work) -> result: error still exists
- allow jenkins user to run scripts with sudo -> result: nvm, npm and node is not defined; I tried to install nvm, npm and node manually but got a new error `permission denied /root/.nvm`

npm log file output looks as follows:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/NodeJS_7.10.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/NodeJS_7.10.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'test' ]
2 info using npm@4.2.0
3 info using node@v7.10.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'pretest', 'test', 'posttest' ]
5 info lifecycle  example@0.0.1~pretest:  example@0.0.1
6 silly lifecycle  example@0.0.1~pretest: no script for pretest, continuing
7 info lifecycle  example@0.0.1~test:  example@0.0.1
8 verbose lifecycle  example@0.0.1~test: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle  example@0.0.1~test: PATH: /var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/NodeJS_7.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleTask/node_modules/.bin:/var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/NodeJS_7.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleTask/node_modules/.bin:/var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/NodeJS_7.10.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin
10 verbose lifecycle  example@0.0.1~test: CWD: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleTask
11 silly lifecycle  example@0.0.1~test: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run lint && karma start' ]
12 silly lifecycle  example@0.0.1~test: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle  example@0.0.1~test: Failed to exec test script
14 verbose stack Error:  example@0.0.1 test: `npm run lint && karma start`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/NodeJS_7.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:279:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:194:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/NodeJS_7.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:899:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid  example@0.0.1
16 verbose cwd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleTask
17 error Linux 4.4.0-1016-aws
18 error argv "/var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/NodeJS_7.10.0/bin/node" "/var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/NodeJS_7.10.0/bin/npm" "run" "test"
19 error node v7.10.0
20 error npm  v4.2.0
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error errno 1
23 error  example@0.0.1 test: `npm run lint && karma start`
23 error Exit status 1
24 error Failed at the  example@0.0.1 test script 'npm run lint && karma start'.
24 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
24 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  example package,
24 error not with npm itself.
24 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
24 error     npm run lint && karma start
24 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
24 error     npm bugs  example
24 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
24 error     npm owner ls  example
24 error There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins node plugin doesn't have correct permissions to perform specific tasks. Provide Jenkins user sudo permissions through base installation of node, and then use commands "sudo command".

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue and was able to resolve by installing Chrome. Note that you may have to set CHROME_BIN environment variable as well.

**For reference:**
I was running Jenkins inside Docker. The js project installed chromedriver as a dependency and I was setting CHROME_BIN to the chromedriver and received the same issue you mentioned (my stack trace is below). Hopefully this is some help or at least helps you moving, good luck.

```
03 01 2018 02:01:20.288:ERROR [karma]: { Error: spawn EACCES
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:328:11)
at exports.spawn (child_process.js:370:9)
at spawnWithoutOutput (/var/jenkins_home/jobs/oh2.0 test/workspace/node_modules/karma/lib/launchers/process.js:168:24)
at Object.ProcessLauncher._execCommand (/var/jenkins_home/jobs/oh2.0 test/workspace/node_modules/karma/lib/launchers/process.js:76:21)
at Object.ProcessLauncher._start (/var/jenkins_home/jobs/oh2.0 test/workspace/node_modules/karma/lib/launchers/process.js:33:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/jenkins_home/jobs/oh2.0 test/workspace/node_modules/karma/lib/launchers/process.js:19:10)
at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
at Object.emit (events.js:188:7)
at Object.BaseLauncher.start (/var/jenkins_home/jobs/oh2.0 test/workspace/node_modules/karma/lib/launchers/base.js:42:10)
at Object.j (/var/jenkins_home/jobs/oh2.0 test/workspace/node_modules/karma/lib/launcher.js:116:17)
at Object.setTimeout.bind.j (/var/jenkins_home/jobs/oh2.0 test/workspace/node_modules/qjobs/qjobs.js:143:18)
at ontimeout (timers.js:386:11)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5) code: 'EACCES', errno: 'EACCES', syscall: 'spawn' }
```